# „als nächstes“ oder „als Nächstes“?

Tags: spelling, standard-german, capitalization, reformed-orthography

Habe hierzu gerade versucht etwas im Internet zu finden, bin aber auf keine zufriedenstellende Antwort gestoßen. Ich vermute ja, dass man es kleinschreibt, bin mir aber gerade nicht so sicher.

Sieht irgendwie blöd aus, wenn ich schreibe „Als Nächstes gehe ich da und dorthin.“, oder?

Habe hierzu mehrere Links gefunden (siehe [hier](http://collabedit.com/euska), da meine Reputation in dieser Community noch nicht groß genug ist).

So wie ich es [hier](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/a/index2.shtml) verstanden habe, geht es aber anscheinend darum, ob man sich an der alten oder neuen Rechtschreibung orientiert, oder? So wird es „als nächstes“ nach der alten und „als Nächstes“ nach der neuen geschrieben, wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe, oder?

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/naechste: "das müssen wir als Nächstes in Angriff nehmen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beides kann richtig sein. Es kommt drauf an, was gemeint ist. Wenn "nächstes" ein Nomen referenziert und somit ein Adjektiv ist, wird es kleingeschrieben. Wenn "Nächstes" jedoch einen Punkt in einer Abfolge von Handlungen beschreibt, schreibt man es groß.
In deinem Fall also Großschreibung.

> Als Nächstes gehe ich da und dorthin.

Sieh dazu auch den Blog von canoonet: [Fährst du als nächstes oder als Nächstes dieses Auto?](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2013/07/29/fahrst-du-als-naechstes-dieses-auto/)

Comment: Ok, dann ist das also etwas Eigenes, dessen Unterscheidung man vom auf dieser Seite beschriebenen Kontext abhängig machen muss.

Anders dürfte es sich da schon bei [diesem Beispiel](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/des_oefteren.shtml) hier verhalten, oder?

Comment: Ja genau, dort wird es immer groß geschrieben. Des Weiteren(!) auch in Folgendem(!). Das gilt aber bei weitem(!) nicht für alles und das nicht erst seit kurzem(!). Im Großen(!) und Ganzen(!) werden aber Adjektive und Partizipien in solchen Fällen substantiviert und folglich großgeschrieben — die meisten(!) zumindest. # Leider muss man das meistens nachschauen, ich vergesse häufig, wann es nun groß- oder kleingeschrieben wird.